Build Failed with verifyReleaseResources Task Error in React Native Square Reader SDK
I'm working on a React Native project where I'm facing an issue with the Square Reader SDK during the release build process. While running the app in release mode using the command npx react-native run-android --mode=release, everything works fine. However, when I try to generate the APK with the command ./gradlew assembleRelease, I encounter the following error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-square-reader-sdk:verifyReleaseResources'.


A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask$Action
Android resource linking failed
ERROR: D:\ReactNative\TestSDK\squareReader\node_modules\react-native-square-reader-sdk\android\build\intermediates\merged_res\release\values\values.xml:17289: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.

Environment:
React Native Version: 0.72.3
Square Reader SDK Version: 1.4.3
Android Build Tools Version: "33.0.0"
Operating System: Windows
Can anyone help me understand why this error is occurring and how to resolve it? Thank you!
What I Tried:
I attempted to build the APK with ./gradlew assembleRelease after successfully running the app in release mode using npx react-native run-android --mode=release.
What I Expected:
I expected the build to complete without errors, generating a release APK for the app.
What Actually Happened:
The build failed with an error during the :react-native-square-reader-sdk:verifyReleaseResources task. The error message indicated a problem with Android resource linking, specifically citing a missing resource attribute (android:attr/lStar) in values.xml.

Step 1:
app/build.gradle file
Add this line on dependencies section
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0'
Step 2:
run this command on terminal
cd android &&  ./gradlew app:assembleRelease && cd ..

If somebody else looking for same or similar error, it mostly happens when using some outdated package which targets some older SDK version.
It is always better to try to update all packages to the latest versions and try to solve issue with that. But if package has no newer version, it is stopped maintaining, then we can skip resource checking during the build time of a release variant. To do so, assemble release variant with a flag
-x verifyReleaseResources
./gradlew assembleRelease -x verifyReleaseResources

